# To sync the different environment what we should do data base refresh or package import

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

I am very new to RSA Archer and want to know about .. 
To sync the different environment what we should do data base refresh or package import.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on how far out of sync your environments are... The further out of sync you should be looking at a full database "refresh".*. Otherwise you should generally develop in environment A and package to other environments and keep up that cycle.

*When I say refresh I mean take a backup of your 'updated' instance environment and then restore your 'out of sync' instance environment using that backup.

Comment: Note - you should restore both Instance and Configuration databases since Configuration database store encryption keys to stored credentials , like LDAP passwords, Data feed account passwords and so on.
Search for environment cloning guide on RSA support portal. They have a detailed step by step document available there.

Answer (score 0):

As "ArcherHero" said - you can clone your instance and configuration databases from one environment to another. This is the fastest way to sync environments. In fact per RSA internal team they sync their internal environments every 3 months (based on 2016 video they published).

You may not have an option to clone databases, in this case you can delete application/questionnaire and install the package from another environment. Don't forget to package the app/questionnaires referencing the module you deleted, roles and workspaces. In addition you need to move data feeds that use deleted module....

So cloning data bases is much faster...